# Firebase Passwordless Signin - Is there a way to generate a email link that does not expire after the first use?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Passwordless Auth using the email link on my website following this Firebase documentation:

- for the frontend: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#complete_sign_in_with_the_email_link) - Angular
- for the backend: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in)  - Python

But even though the link generated by the function `generate_sign_in_with_email_link()` works fine the first time, it only works once:

```py
from firebase_admin import auth

link = f'http://localhost:4200/login'
dynamic_link_domain = 'test.page.link'

action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
    url=link,
    dynamic_link_domain=dynamic_link_domain
)
link = auth.generate_sign_in_with_email_link("test@gmail.com", action_code_settings)
```

When the user tries to click a second time I get this error:

> The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.

This is not the behavior I want. I'm looking for a "magic link" that the user can click on multiple times and still be logged in to my website. Is this possible with Firebase? What is the right configuration to apply?

Comment: Those links are for one time use only. If you want a link that never expires you can always generate one with a custom token yourself. Though it won't be much secure since the token never expires.

Comment: But don't custom tokens have an expiration time as well (1 hour) ? [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

Comment: By that I essential meant building your own solution for that. Like generating tokens yourself, storing them in database if needed and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But even though the link generated by the function generate_sign_in_with_email_link() works fine the first time, it only works once.

That's the expected behavior. When you send a user an email containing an authentication link, once it is used the link expires. Why? So other users cannot use it. If you try to use it again, that error message appears.

> I'm looking for a "magic link" that the user can click on multiple times and still be logged in to my website

To achieve that you should consider using another type of authentication. For example, email and password, or any other provider, like Google, Facebook, etc. In this way, you'll always be able to authenticate into the same account.

There is, however, a solution in which you can use custom tokens but as also @Dharmaraj already mentioned in his comment, that wouldn't be so secure.

Comment: But don't custom tokens have an expiration time as well (1 hour) ? [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

Comment: No, those are tokens provided by third-party JWT library. I was referring to creating custom tokens yourself, that can never expire. But as I already mentioned in my answer, isn't the best solution, since those tokens can be reused.

Comment: Ok for my own custom token, but how, in the front can I sign the user in  since I only have access to his email and not his password. Clearly I cannot use the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` nor `signInWithEmailLink` functions.

Comment: If you want to use email and password authentication, there is no need to handle the tokens. You might also consider using [Firebase anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) if you'd like.

Comment: This will need another question. Thanks