# How to create a Magic Link with Firebase to login a user instantly every time he use it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

## What I want

I have a list of people with all their personal information (name, first name, date of birth, email, etc.). I created an account for each of these people using their email/phone + a password I generated for them.

I want to send to each of these people an email/SMS with a link allowing them, once clicked :

- to be directly connected on our website, without having to type a password or using a third party as Google/Facebook/etc.
- and I want the link not to expire after the first use. The user must be able to click on it several times and be connected to our website each time.

## What I tried

This is what I tried so far, unsuccessfully :

- Passwordless Auth with email link: using both [backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in) and [frontend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page). Doesn't fit my needs because the [signin link works only once by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447404/firebase-passwordless-signin-is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-email-link-that-does).
- Create a [custom token with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens): as I understood, the token will [expire 3600 seconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) after creation, which is not useful for me.
- [Implement anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth): it still need the user to [type email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#email-password-sign-in) at some point if you want to convert the anonymous account to a permanent account (because I don't want to use Google/Facebook/etc auth). Plus, it will need consequent changes in all my website code to work.

**At this point I realized that Firebase doesn't have a solution that fits my needs. I started to fiddled around as best I could.**

## The idea

It works as the following:

1. First I create an account for the user in Firebase + a unique document in a collection in Firestore. That document contains 3 fields: `magic_token`, `email`, `password`.
2. Then, I create a link to our website with a unique token as a parameter in it. I store the token  as `magic_token` in the document I described above. I send the link to the user.
3. The user clicks on the link, get redirected to my website. In the front, I detect  the presence of the token in the parameters of the URL, I retrieve the document in Firestore with the corresponding token.
4. Using the `email` and `password` stored in this document I call: `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` to login the user.

PROS:

- it fits my needs.
- it is easy to implement

CONS:

- the user password is visible in Firestore.
- it's not very secure.

## The question

Is there a proper way to implement a Magic Link that fit my needs? If not, how can I improve my own custom token authentication ?

Comment: It looks like an [integration with Magic](https://magic.link/posts/magic-firebase-integration#auth_data_flow) is what you are looking for. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: @FaridShumbar could be a solution indeed. But I'm not sure: 1) if the magic link will be reusable. 2) if the user can skip the first step when he has to type again his email. I'll contact them. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor unfortunately there is no way to do exactly that. There is some workarounds but I have to change mes expectations a little bit.